# Building a surjective function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let F be a field and X, Y two F-linear subspaces with $dim_FX=n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $dim_FY=m\in \mathbb{N}$.
Show that:
There is a surjective F-linear mapping f:X$\rightarrow Y \iff n\geq m$

I have proven the $\Rightarrow$-direction.

Now:

Let $n\geq m$.
Let $(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ be a basis of Y and let $ (x_1,...,x_m, x_{m+1},...,x_n) $ be a basis of X.

Can someone please explain me how i build a surjective F-linear function out of that?

Do i use a Transformation and use Theorem "SLTB" of http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-SLT.html ?

So basicly i just say $Tx_i=y_i$ is surjective by the theorem and be done? (since $\{y_i\}_i$ is indeed the spanning set of Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. For $1 \leq i \leq m$ define $T(x_i) = y_i$. For $m+1 \leq i \leq n$ define $T(x_i) = y_m$. Then extend $T$ linearly to all of $X$. This is clearly surjective.

Comment: hi, what you mean with "then extend $T$ linearly to all of $X$" was this a "order" to me, or to the reader of the proof?

Comment: It is a note to the reader of the proof. If you define what to do with the basis, then it defines a linear transformation on the entire vector space  by the linearity properties:

$T(a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n) = a_1T(x_1) + \dots a_nT(x_n)$